For a locally compact group that is not unimodular, find a Borel set that is finite for a left Haar measure and infinite for a right Haar measure
I am stuck with a fairly easy exercice:
Let $G$ be a locally compact topological group that is not unimodular with left Haar measure $\mu$ on $G$. Show that there exists a Borel set $A$ such that $\mu(A)<\infty$ and $\check{\mu}(A):=\mu(A^{-1})=\infty$ ($\check{\mu}$ is a right Haar measure).
Idea: the modular function $\Delta$ is not bounded and $\check{\mu}(xA)=\Delta(x^{-1})\check{\mu}(A)$, so that $\check{\mu}(xA)$ can be made arbitrarily large with the right choice of $A$ (while $\mu(xA)=\mu(A)$). Yet I can't see how to conclude from here.What am I missing?
I think the answer must be easy, but I'm stuck. Thanks for your help.
